# R function from string cell YEARMonth as date?

Tags: r, lubridate, as.date

So I have this long dataset, where in one column I have a date specified as character in format YYYMMM, but month abbreviated. So for example 1995MAR, 1995APR and so on. How can I transform that to date format?

I tried as.Date but it obviously hasn't worked, and with lubridate::ymd which hasn't worked as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using `parse_date_time` from `lubridate`

```
date <- "1995MAR"
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(date, order = "Yb")
```

Output:

```
[1] "1995-03-01 UTC"
```

Alternatively using `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
as.Date(as.yearmon(date, '%Y%b'))
```

Output:

```
"1995-03-01"

str(as.Date(as.yearmon(date, '%Y%b')))

Date[1:1], format: "1995-03-01"
```

Comment: The output chunk needs to be fixed too to correspond to the input shown.

Comment: Perfect, that works like a charm. I do want to ask for additional example, if I only have a year, so in some instances I have just 2002 for example. I tried with parse_date_time(date, order = "Y"), but no sucess...

Comment: @matfan if you add the argument truncated=2L to the parse_date_time does that work for your year only date?

Comment: If you have a character vector in which some entries are year/month in the format shown in the question and some entries just have the year such as 
`x <- c("2000MAR", "2001")` then this will convert them all to Date class
`as.Date(as.yearmon(paste0(x, "Jan"), "%Y%b"))` as it ignores junk on the end or omit the `as.Date` to get all yearmon entries..

Answer (score 1):

In Base R, add a day number to parse:

```r
date <- "1995MAR"
as.Date(paste(date, "01"), format = "%Y%b %d")
#[1] "1995-03-01"
```